# Extending UIControl to Assign a Startup Value for Persistence

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

StackOverflow,

I am working to extend UIControl to assign a single value to itself. This is implemented so it can assign a value on startup for persistence. My goal is to do this as generally as possible so it is easily extendable. One of the main components of my approach is switching on the type of UIControl. For instance, if it is a switch I need to assign a bool and if is a text view I need to assign a string. Yet, it gives me a few errors given below:

> Cast from 'UIControl' to unrelated type 'UITextView' always fails
>
> Expression pattern of type 'Bool' cannot match values of type
>   'UIControl'

I understand that this code is completely wrong but I have found no other approach. What is your suggestion to implement this method? Am I on the right track?

```
extension UIControl {
    func assignValue(value: Any?){
        switch(self){
        case self is UISwitch:
            (self as! UISwitch).isOn = value as! Bool
        case self is UITextView:
            (self as! UITextView).text = value as! String
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Macro

Comment: I fixed one of my errors by adding "case self where self is UISwitch" but it will still return only one value. My goal is for this method to be inherited by all UIControls and be used to set the value. I want to loop through a list of control elements in order to set their state. Does that help clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

self.hello(),

The syntax errors can be fixed by matching true to the case in which the object is of type UISwitch, UITextView, etc. All UIControl elements will inherit this method. It might be better to separately extend each UIElements that is implemented so they don't all have the function.

```
extension UIControl {
    func assignValue(object: AnyObject, value: Any){
        switch(true){
        case object is UISwitch:
            (object as! UISwitch).isOn = value as! Bool
        case object is UITextView:
            (object as! UITextView).text = value as! String
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

self.thanks()